# What is the best unit testing tool for a mix of managed and unmanaged C++?

Tags: c++, unmanaged, managed-c++

I am going to start implementing some unit tests for a codebase that is a mix of managed and unmanaged C++. Can NUnit hack it with unmanaged code? Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to use NUnit to test unmanaged code, example:

```
// Tests.h

#pragma once

#include <cmath>

using namespace System;
using namespace NUnit::Framework;

namespace Tests {

    [TestFixture]
    public ref class UnitTest
    {
    public:
        UnitTest(void) {}

        [Test]
        void TestCos()
        {
            Assert::AreEqual(1, cos(0.0));
        }

    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

NUnit will work fine with unmanaged code as long as you write the unit tests in managed C++.  The outside wrapper will be NUnit friendly and can access the unmanaged parts.